# Like/liked - meaning difference in given context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

If you get someone a book for a present and want feedback on whether they liked/like it, do you say "Let me know how you **like** it." Or "Let me know how you **liked** it."

What's the difference between the two sentences here?

Comment: In practice, very few native speakers would use *either* of the suggested alternatives, even though they're both perfectly valid English. What we normally say in such contexts is *Let me know **if** you like it* (where in principle you could also use the "past in the future" form *...if you **liked** it*, but actually no-one would normally do this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are possible. There is no objective difference.

The only difference is of temporal focus. If you say *liked*, you are setting the temporal focus at the time when they tell you, so that the liking is then in the past; if you say *like*, you are not setting any temporal focus.

In this case, I cannot think of any consequence arising from that difference in temporal focus, so I can't find any practical difference.